# Declaration or statement expected in else statement

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to java script and I've encountered a problem while trying to make a else statement in visual studio 2017.

I've tried moving the curly brackets and the else around to see if maybe I've placed them into the wrong place and I've had no luck.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 var items = parseInt(prompt("enter number of items", ""));
 var price = parseFloat(prompt("enter item price", ""));
 var total = items * price 
        if (total >= 50); {
            document.write("<h3>" + "cost... $" + total * .5 + "</h3>");
            document.write("<h2>" + prompt("enter a name", "") + "</h2>");
        } 
        else {
            document.write("<h3>" + "cost... $" + total + "</h3>");
            document.write("<h2>" + prompt("enter a name", "") + "</h2>");
        }
        
    </script>
```

Whenever I open it in a web page, nothing happens, But when i get rid of the else statement, the if statement would execute.

Comment: You look to have a typo at `if (total >= 50);` where you've left that semi-colon there. Remove the semi-colon and everything should work!

Comment: you added `;` after if i.e. `if (total >= 50);`

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Delete the semicolon behind the if condition and then the code should work.